# R dplyr - running total with row-wise calculations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that keeps track of the activities associated with a bank account (example below).

The initial balance is $5,000 (**type** "initial). If **type** is "in", that means a cash deposit. In this example each deposit is $1,000. If **type** is "out", that means a withdrawal from the account. In this example each withdrawal is 10% of the account balance.

```
data <- tibble(
  activity=1:6,
  type=c("initial","in","out","out","in","in"),
  input=c(5000,1000,10,10,1000,1000))
```

Is there a dplyr solution to keep track of the balance **after** each activity?? I have tried several ways but I can't seem to find a way to efficiently calculate running totals and the withdrawal amount (which depends on the running total).

For this example the output should be:

```
result <- tibble(
  activity=1:6,
  type=c("initial","in","out","out","in","in"),
  input=c(5000,1000,10,10,1000,1000),
  balance=c(5000,6000,5400,4860,5860,6860))
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or recommendations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `purrr::accumulate2()` to condition the calculation on the value of `type`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(balance = accumulate2(input, type[-1], .f = function(x, y, type) if(type == "out") x - x * y/100 else x + y)) %>%
  unnest(balance) 

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  activity type    input balance
     <int> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1        1 initial  5000    5000
2        2 in       1000    6000
3        3 out        10    5400
4        4 out        10    4860
5        5 in       1000    5860
6        6 in       1000    6860
```

Comment: I was working with a similar option `data %>% mutate(balance = purrr::accumulate2(input, type[-1], ~ if(..3 == 'in') ..2 + ..1 else  ..1 - ..1 * ..2/100)) %>% unnest(c(balance))`

Comment: Thanks for providing a working solution in such a short time-frame. It is definitely more elegant compared to my while-loop approach.